# Why one head file can use other head files directly without include them

Tags: c

It is on VS Code
first I have `type.h`

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef unsigned long long uint64;
```

then I have `defs.h`

```
uint fun1(uint);
uint64 fun2(uint64);
```

then is the `main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "types.h"
#include "defs.h"

uint fun1(uint x) {
  return x;
}
uint64 fun2(uint64 x) {
  return x;
}
int main() {
  printf("%d, %llu\n", fun1(10), fun2(20));

  return 0;
}
```

I mean why can I use `uint` and `uint64` in `defs.h` that are defined in `types.h` without including it, and the IntelliSense plug doesn't give me warnings

Comment: What you're describing is not possible.  There's "something else" at play that you're not telling us.  Perhaps the definitions you think must come only from b.h are defined elsewhere.  Or perhaps a.h isn't really dependent on b.h after all.  It's impossible to say without more details - including a specific, concrete example.

Comment: Typically what will happen is any translation unit that includes `a.h` will somehow, by some means, have included `b.h` already. That may be explicit, or via some other header. Or it may be that those definitions are not used. For instance, they may be part of a template.

Comment: `#include` is a directive to stop processing the current file and process the contents of the specified file before continuing. If two files are included, then all the definitions in the first will be processed before the second, so they will be available in that file - in this specific instance. If the first file is not included, then the second will fail, so this is not a smart thing to do - files should always include files they depend on, and should always have a guard to prevent processing twice if they are included twice.

Comment: I think OP's problem here is understanding that only `main.c` is actually a translation unit. The headers are not being looked at in isolation by the compiler, only in the context of their inclusion in `main.c`, which includes `types.h` before `defs.h`. (Which is, as @JohnBayko pointed out, bad practice -- but syntactically perfectly valid.)

Answer (score 0):

Header files are not processed in isolation. In `main.c`, you have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "types.h"
#include "defs.h"
…
```

When the compiler is asked to compile `main.c`, it reads the line `#include <stdio.h>`. That line tells the compiler to read `<stdio.h>` and **process the contents of `<stdio.h>` as if they were in `main.c`**. That continues with each `#include` directive; the contents of the included file become part of the source code being compiled.

Thus, the result of those three directives is as if `main.c` contained, in part:

```
…
typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef unsigned long long uint64;

uint fun1(uint);
uint64 fun2(uint64);
…
```

So when the compiler is processing `uint fun1(uint);` from `"defs.h"`, it has already seen `typedef unsigned int uint` from `"types.h"`.

If you instructed the compiler to compile `defs.h` as C source code alone, or to compile a source file that included `defs.h` but did not include `types.h`, then the compiler would not have the definitions of `uint` and `uint64` and would complain about their use.

It is generally good practice for each header file to have a `#include` directive for each header file that provides definitions or declarations that the file needs, so your `defs.h` should have a line `#include "types.h"`. (There may be exceptions to this.)